# when to check for file size/mimetype in node.js upload script?

Tags: file-upload, node.js

I created an upload script in node.js using express/formidable. It basically works, but I am wondering where and when to check the uploaded file e. g. for the maximum file size or if the file´s mimetype is actually allowed.

My program looks like this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        // ... do stuff
    });

    req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log('\nuploaded %s to %s',  files.image.filename, files.image.path);
        // ... do stuff    
    });
});
```

It seems to me that the only viable place for checking the mimetype/file size is the `complete` event where I can reliably use the filesystem functions to get the size of the uploaded file in `/tmp/` – but that seems like a not so good idea because:

- the possibly malicious/too large file is already uploaded on my server
- the user experience is poor – you watch the upload progress just to be told that it didnt work afterwards

Whats the best practice for implementing this? I found quite a few examples for file uploads in node.js but none seemed to do the security checks I would need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With help from some guys at the node IRC and the node mailing list, here is what I do:

I am using formidable to handle the file upload. Using the `progress` event I can check the maximum filesize like this:

```
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    if (bytesReceived > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE) {
        console.log('### ERROR: FILE TOO LARGE');
    }
});
```

Reliably checking the mimetype is much more difficult. The basic Idea is to use the `progress` event, then if enough of the file is uploaded use a `file --mime-type` call and check the output of that external command. Simplified it looks like this:

```
// contains the path of the uploaded file, 
// is grabbed in the fileBegin event below
var tmpPath; 

form.on('progress', function validateMimetype(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
    var percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;

    // pretty basic check if enough bytes of the file are written to disk, 
    // might be too naive if the file is small!
    if (tmpPath && percent > 25) {
        var child = exec('file --mime-type ' + tmpPath, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            var mimetype = stdout.substring(stdout.lastIndexOf(':') + 2, stdout.lastIndexOf('\n'));

            console.log('### file CALL OUTPUT', err, stdout, stderr);

            if (err || stderr) {
                console.log('### ERROR: MIMETYPE COULD NOT BE DETECTED');
            } else if (!ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES[mimetype]) {
                console.log('### ERROR: INVALID MIMETYPE', mimetype);
            } else {
                console.log('### MIMETYPE VALIDATION COMPLETE');
            }
        });

        form.removeListener('progress', validateMimetype);
    }
});

form.on('fileBegin', function grabTmpPath(_, fileInfo) {
    if (fileInfo.path) {
        tmpPath = fileInfo.path;
        form.removeListener('fileBegin', grabTmpPath);
    }
});
```

Comment: @CIRK its working, however I just used it in some pet project, not in production. The request is closed later in the controller (I am using express.js as framework). If you are interested, feel free to take a look at the complete source of this project on github: https://github.com/maxbeutel/nodejs.fileupload - I never completely finished it though, but it was an interesting adventure in node.js ;)

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Connect (2.x.) has this already baked into the `bodyParser` using the limit middleware: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js#L44-61

I think it's much better this way as you just kill the request when it exceeds the maximum limit instead of just stopping the formidable parser (and letting the request "go on").

More about the limit middleware: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/limit.html