# In Node.JS, when I do a POST request, what is the maximum size?

Tags: http, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when to check for file size/mimetype in node.js upload script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322054/when-to-check-for-file-size-mimetype-in-node-js-upload-script)

In Node.JS, when I do a POST request, what is the maximum size? Where do I set it, if any? I'm using Express.

Comment: You should read the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322054/when-to-check-for-file-size-mimetype-in-node-js-upload-script Also, as far as I know you can set a MAX file size for uploading with POST using formidable (or using Express > 2.5.x since it integrates connect-form in it).